# How to get position:fixed; behavior with scroll bar

Tags: html, css, scroll, fixed

I have a webpage, divided into 2 columns : left and right.

Left side - all new orders in HTML link form. 
Right Side - Clicking on link will fetch the order detail via AJAX CALL and display response on RHS.

I set the Right side position:fixed; so i can scroll down and click any "new order link". so content can be seen right away (without scrolling up).

The problem is if response content is too much (more than  size of screen), its not display scroll for contents.

How to solve this issue. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `overflow:scroll;` on the right `div` CSS or whatever element it is.

Or more specifically `overflow-y:scroll;`

Comment: Thanks for response. Its adding the scroll. But Its kind of dummy scroll. its not usable

Comment: I was using the height:auto. That's why scroll was not working. Thanks